# Python subprocess.call() doesn't write content to file

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, subprocess

Using Python 2.7 on Raspberry Pi B+, I want to call the command "raspistill -o image.jpg" from Python and find using this is recommended:

```
from subprocress import call
call(["raspistill","-o image.jpg"])
```

However, this doesn't work since the image.jpg isn't created although outside Python,

```
raspistill -o
```

does create the file.
Next try is to first create the image file and writing to it.

```
f = open("image.jpg","w")
call(["raspistill","-o image.jpg"], stdout = f)
```

Now the image file is created, but nothing is written to it: its size remains 0. So how can I get this to work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are passing `-o image.jpg` as a single argument. You should pass them like two. Here is how:

```
call(["raspistill", "-o", "image.jpg"])
```

The way you did it it's like calling `raspistill "-o image.jpg"` from the command line, which will likely result in an error.

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, without f=open("image.jpg","w") with this change there is still no file created. Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: @user2294285: see @abarnert's response.  Having both means you have two programs (python and raspistill) attempting to write to the same file at the same time - at best a mess.  At the very least you should call `f.close()` *before* you run raspistill.

Comment: @user2294285 I suggest you try `subprocess.check_output(["raspl..."])`. If  the file is not created then there is probably an error. The above command should print the error. Please post the error here and I'll try to guide you further.

Comment: I removed the f=open(). The output of `check_output` is `CalledProcessError: Command "["raspistill"," -o", "image.jpg"]" returned non-zero exit status 64`

Comment: @user2294285 look up exit status 64 for raspistill. If that doesn't help I suggest you open a file for writing and then call `subprocess.call` with the param `stderr=file_for_writing`. This should write the error to that file. Post the error here afterwards.

Comment: I can't find status 64 and get the error that the param `file_for_writing` is not defined.

Comment: @user2294285: `file_for_writing` was meant as an example filename, not literally.

Comment: @user2294285: after some digging through the raspistill source code I found that error 64 is `EX_USAGE 64 /* command line usage error */`.  This is coming from `parse_cmdline` and is raised for invalid command-line parameters.  I suggest you try the command on the command line first and get that working before trying to run it through python.

Comment: @cdarke: I used  `raspistill -o image.jpg` at the command-line to begin with and that works fine. After that I've tried to run it through Python using `call`. So I guess that the error indicates that the way the command-line takes the command after being issued by `call` is wrong. Which means imo that I have to change the formatting inside the `call` instruction.

Comment: @user2294285  OK.  I noticed in a previous comment that one parameter was `" -o"`.  If that is what you really gave then that is the source of your error.  The source code shows that raspistill looks for a `-` as the first character  ( `if (argv[i][0] != '-')` ), but in this case it will be a space.  On the command-line/shell the space would be removed since it is a delimiter.  So, remove all whitespace from inside the quotes on the parameters and try again.

Comment: @cdarke: The space in front of the `-o` was indeed the culprit. The code works fine now. The reason I inserted the space was because of a few examples I found. Those prove wrong. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

First, you're creating and truncating the file `image.jpg`:

```
f = open("image.jpg","w")
```

Then you're sending `raspistill`'s stdout to that same file:

```
call(["raspistill","-o image.jpg"], stdout = f)
```

When you eventually get around to `close`-ing the file in Python, now `image.jpg` is just going to hold whatever `raspistill` wrote to stdout. Or, if you never `close` it, it'll be that minus the last buffer, which may be nothing at all.

Meanwhile, you're also trying to get `raspistill` to create a file with the same name, by passing it as part of the `-o` argument. You're doing that wrong, as [Ionut Hulub's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30477414/9084940) explains. Some programs will take `"-o image.jpg"` `"-oimage.jpg"`, and `"-o", "image.jpg"` as meaning the same thing, some won't. But, even if this one does, at best you've now got two programs fighting over what file gets created and written as `image.jpg`.

If `raspistill` has an option to write the still to stdout, then you can use *that* option, together with passing `stdout=f`, and making sure to `close` the file. Or, if it has an option to write to a filename, then you can use *that* option. But doing *both* is not going to work.

Comment: Thank you for your response, although I find it confusing. `f=open("image.jpg")` doesn't create a file. Of course I close the file after the call. I've tried with your suggestions, and use `"raspistill","-o","image.jpg"` but so far there is no improvement.

Comment: @user2294285: Yes, `f=open("image.jpg", "w")` does create a file. Unless a file with that name already exists, in which case it opens and truncates that file. That's exactly what it's for.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know how to split the command, you can use `shlex.split`. For example,

```
>>> import shlex
>>> args = shlex.split('raspistill -o image.jpg')
>>> args
['raspistill', '-o', 'image.jpg']
>>> call(args)
```